# Django Channels - Unable To Message Channel Directly When A Member Of A Group

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have a requirement within my application to be able to message both individual channels and groups of channels depending on the situation.

I have come across the issue however, that if I add my channels to a group, I am no longer able to message them directly.

Here are some examples:

(Unable to send to a single channel):

```
class NonWorkingExampleConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.group_name = 'group'
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        
        self.accept()
    
    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        
    def receive(self, text_data):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)(
            self.channel_name,
            {
                'type' : 'test',
                'message' : 'Hello World!'
            }
        )
        
    def test(self, event):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message' : event['message']
        }))
```

(Able to send to a single channel):

```
class WorkingExampleConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):       
        self.accept()
    
    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass
        
    def receive(self, text_data):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)(
            self.channel_name,
            {
                'type' : 'test',
                'message' : 'Hello World!'
            }
        )
        
    def test(self, event):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message' : event['message']
        }))
```

So, My question is: Is this a bug or am I simply doing something wrong? I was considering opening a ticket on Django Channels GitHub, but it suggested checking on StackOverflow first to make sure it was definitely a bug and not user error (which is a real possibility!)

I am using Django version 3.1 ,Django Channels version 3.0.2 and Django Channels Redis Version 3.2.0. Here are my Redis settings:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('192.168.15.82', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the person to send a message to himself? because that is what your current code is trying to do. If you want that, then there really is no need sending through the channel layer. You can just call `self.send` directly in the `receive` method. Given that `self.channel_name` is the sender's channel, the code just sends a  message back to the sender

Comment: I've simplified my code a great deal just to give an example of the issue. What's actually happening in my app is I have several different handler functions doing different jobs depending on the data it receives from the client. Some of these functions only need to return data to the same user and some need to return data top ALL users. So in my case, I will need to use a combination of send and group_send, but as described the former no longer seems to work once a channel has been added to a group.

Comment: Hi @Ken4scholars and Dan Alderman: would love your thoughts on my question here, please. Similar issue but it's not really going away.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172488/django-channels-group-send-getting-delayed-while-sending-to-active-window-whe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure as to why, but after a nights sleep and some tinkering with my code this now appears to be working as intended.

That does indeed answer the question, it was user error all along!

Sorry for wasting your time, but thanks very much for attempting to solve the issue.