# Django Channels: group_send() getting delayed while sending to active window when a user has multiple windows open

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, channel

Background: I'm working on a chat application on my local (development) server. Python 3.9.5, Django 3.2, Channels 3.0.3. Each user can see an "all messages" section on the page, containing messages from all users, and a "my messages" section, containing only his own messages.

Goal: All messages should be sent to all users, and each user's messages should be separately sent only to him/her. If the user is logged in via multiple browser tabs/ devices (this scenario is supposed to be handled by Channels as per the docs [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html#groups)), and the user sends a message from one window, it needs to immediately send back (echo) the message to all his windows, including the window where the message was sent from.

For this, I'm adding each connection to a group when it is first opened.

Consumers.py

```py
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):

        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })

        await self.channel_layer.group_add("master", self.channel_name)

        user = self.scope['user']
        user_group = "user_" + str(user.id)
        
        if user.is_authenticated:
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(user_group, self.channel_name)
```

As you can see, the master group is for all users, and the user_group is for all connections of this particular user.

Further:

```py
    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        user = self.scope['user']
        user_group = "user_" + str(user.id)
        
        #....some code...

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            "master",{
                'type': 'master.broadcast',
                'text': json.dumps(messages_all)
            }
        )
        
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            user_group,{
                'type': 'user.broadcast',
                'text': json.dumps(messages_user)
            }
        )
```

The broadcast functions are simple send functions:

```py
    async def master_broadcast(self, event):
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event['text']
        })
    
    async def user_broadcast(self, event):
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event['text']
        })
```

The problem:

When the user sends a message from one of his windows, all connections in the `"master"` group (from the first `group_send()`) are successfully getting the messages, except the user's own active window from which the message was sent. Here, there's a delay of about 10-20 seconds, after which the user's active window receives the master message. Immediately, all the other messages (to `user_group`, via the second `group_send()`) are sent without any more delay (including the active window).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Grateful for any help here. To be clear, if the user is logged in from only 1 window/tab, there's no problem and the messages are delivered instantly.

P.S: I have already tried sending messages from each of the different windows of the user. In each case, the delay is only in the case of the window that is sending the message. SO this has nothing to do with the browsers being used etc.